# local development versus live deployment - no PHP output

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

Im building a small JS/PHP based game.
For development, i have decided to develop it on my windows machine using a portable dev stack, in this case SecureWAMP.
On my windows machine, my "project" is working without flaws, i have a proper login/logout page, a debug-class and i can echo / var_dump errors.

I now created a GIT repo out of it and pulled this repo onto an AWS instance.
Now, when i open the index.php on the live websever, i see my the actual page, including the javascript and html buildup.
However, upon trying to login or register, i only receive a 100 % white page in return. No echo/var_dump occurs and and also my debug class is not generating any content in the specified logfile.

Since this is my very first "real" project, im at a loss for what could be wrong.
Going by the all white blank screen (upon clicking a button that would post a form), are there any guesses on what might be causing my problem ?

For reference, here is a link to my index.php on Github
https://github.com/AncientSion/projectX/blob/master/index.php

- thanks

Comment: Make sure to enable PHP error reporting and make sure to check if there's an error_log in the root of your project folder on AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An often-made mistake in cases like this is to forget about case. Windows uses filesystems that are not case-sensitive; other operating systems don't do that.

An easy way to avoid that problem is to *always* use lower case when referring to other files; that is, don't do `include "Foo.inc"`, but do `include "foo.inc"` instead; then, also make sure that the file names (when you do a git checkout...) are in lowercase